# Trouble with css cells not sticking

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get the the left and write columns to stick to the bottom of the green box like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fLnD.png but after an hour I'm still having trouble, if anyone could help that would be most appreciated, thank you very much http://jsfiddle.net/jybu6j47/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.well {
height: 300px;
width: 50%;
background-color:green;
}
.something {
background-color: yellow;
}
.left123 {
width: 50%;
float: left;
background-color: pink;
}
.right123 {
width: 50%;
float: right;
text-align:right;
background-color:red;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
    Filler
    <div class="something">
        <div class="left123">Left</div>
        <div class="right123">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jybu6j47/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `position:relative;` the container, and `position:absolute;` the contents, then set `bottom: 0` on the contents like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jybu6j47/1/

So it should look like this:

```
.well {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}
.something {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Position absolute tells an element exactly where to be, relative to it's closest `position:relative` (or absolute – or a couple of other properties come to think of it) container. In this case, giving it `bottom:0` is effectively saying "Put me zero pixels from the bottom of the container".